# Jasmine Js - SpyOn Fakecall during the controller initialization

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, spyon

I have seen a set of duplicates for this question but was unable to solve the issue.

I have a controller and during the controller initialization, fetchtemplate() is getting called first and then my mock fetchtemplate() is getting called.

How do I stop the actual(controller) fetchtemplate() getting called during the controller initialization? My intention is to mock the function fetchtemplate() in my spec.Please have a look at my spec -

```
describe("...",function(){
   beforeEach(inject(function($controller,...) {
   scope        =   $rootScope.$new();

   this.init = function() {
                  $controller('ChangeControlCreateController', {
                    $scope: scope
                  });
                }
    }));
    describe('Function', function() {

        it("-- check for trueness",function(){

        this.init()     ; //Initialization of the controller
        spyOn(scope,'fetchtemplate').and.callFake(function() {
                  return 101;
                });
        var fakeResponse = scope.fetchtemplate();
        expect(scope.fetchtemplate).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(fakeResponse).toEqual(101);      
        });


    });
});
```

I have tried placing the spyOn before the `this.init()` which gave error as the `fetchtemplate()` doesn't exist at that time to spyOn.

My controller code structure looks like -

```
angular.module('...', [...])

  .controller('ChangeControlCreateController', ["$scope"...,
    function ChangeControlCreateController($scope,...) {
        $scope.fetchtemplate = function() {
            console.log("controller's function");            
            ...
        };
        $scope.fetchtemplate();
    });
```

The result what I am getting is - First the console item "controller's function" and then the spec is executing with mock function. I want the mock function to execute **without** the controller's function to execute

Comment: can you give us the controller code too ? I need to see how you call that fetchtemplate method

Comment: sure, I have added the controller code structure as well. @sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand correctly you are doing some call to a function that is doing something you want to prevent for test purposes. Probably an http call or some thing of the sort ?

Whatever it is doing the proper way to handle something like that is usually to put that method inside a service instead and then to spy on that service method. Here is an example of test  if the service is TemplateService :

```
describe("...",function(){

var $controller, scope, TemplateService, YourController;

beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _TemplateService_, ...) {
  scope = $rootScope.$new();
  $controller = _$controller_;
  TemplateService = _TemplateService_;  
}

it("-- check for trueness",function(){

  spyOn(TemplateService,'fetchTemplate').and.returnValue('101');

YourController = $controller('YourController'); 
  expect(...);
});


});
```

I hope that's helpful

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for the reply. Can I resolve the issue without putting my function in the service?

Comment: You could probably by overriding angular basic behaviours or else by some means I never found out yet. As you said you cannot intervene on something that does not exist yet